# Refresh information gotten from navigation property EF

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, data-binding, entity-framework-4

I have an Enity Model contains a UsersList entity associated to UserTasks with UserID. UserTasks is loaded in a DataGrid, I'm getting the UserName from UsersList using `NavigationProperty`. I've made a simple ChildWindow linked to the DataGrid's `SelectedItem` to edit selected task including the user (which is my problem).

when selecting another user from a ComboBox and other information, All are updating normally in the DataGrid except the user Name.

I did debug to see if the UserTasks object got the new UserID, I found that it did.

What's missing to get DataGrid refresh the task's user name ?

Comment: Any code for us to work with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I resolved my problem I just missed to set `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`